# How do I link to my model to its foreign key and manytomany fields in the templates in django?

Tags: django, templates, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I am new to django and have a rather basic question, however I have not been able to find my answer online, so apologies if this has been answered previously...

I have 3 models:

```
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    exercise = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise)
```

and 3 views:

```
class AreaView(ListView):
    model = Area
    template_name = 'workouts/areas.html'
    context_object_name = 'areas'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AreaView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class ExerciseView(ListView):
    model = Area
    template_name = 'workouts/exercises.html'
    context_object_name = 'exercises'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExerciseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class TypeView(ListView):
    model = Exercise
    template_name = 'workouts/types.html'
    context_object_name = 'types'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TypeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

I have registered each view to a url like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', AreaView.as_view(), name='areas'),
    path('exercises/<int:id>', ExerciseView.as_view(), name='exercises'),
    path('types/<int:id>', TypeView.as_view(), name='types'),
]
```

and created 3 templates, areas.html:

```
{% for area in areas %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'exercises' id=area.id %}">{{ area.name }}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

exercises.html:

```
{% for area in areas %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'types' id=exercise.id %}">{% for exercise in area.exercise.all %}{{ exercise }}{% endfor %}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

and types.html:

```
{% for exercise in exercises %}
    <ul>
        <li>{% for type in exercise.type.all %}{{ type}}{% endfor %}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I have added specific exercises to each area in the admin, as well as specific types to each exercise. What i am trying to do is display a full list of all areas in `areas.html` which then link to a list of their corresponding exercises in `exercises.html`, which in turn then link to a page which shows each exercises corresponding types. Hope that makes sense... I have tried playing around with different naming conventions for context and for loops and such, but so far nothing has worked out the way i want it to.

Do I need to define a queryset in the views or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the DetailView.

```
class AreaDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Area
    context_object_name = 'area'
    template_name = 'exercises.html'
```

And map this detail view to the url like this.

```
path('area/<int:pk>/detail/', AreaDetailView.as_view(), name='area_detail'),
```

Now you can link this url in your template.

```
{% for area in areas %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'area_detail' area.pk %}">{{ area.name }}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Now in the `exercise.html` you can get the related exercise of this area like this.

```
{% for exercise in area.exercise_set.all %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'exercise_detail' id=exercise.id %}">{{ exercise.name }}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Similarly you can use the similar approach with the ExerciseDetailView

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That almost worked, I just had to change the for loop in `exercises.html` to `{% for exercise in area.exercise.all %}` and it was perfect. However using the same technique on `types.html`, i.e. `{% for type in exercise.type.all %}` and `{{ type.name }}` is displaying only an empty page. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: it should be `{{exercise.type}}`  only and remove the forloop if you want to display the type of exercise.

Comment: Legend. Now it is perfect. Thank you so much!